# How would I make elements move faster when resizing browser?

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to make elements move faster when the browser is resized, as the browser is doing it too slow as you can see [here](https://youtu.be/kJq8MuUJru4). I used percents and this is the code I used on the huge block.

```
.center {display: inline-block; margin-left: 20%;}
```

How would I make it so the element moves faster when resized?  All I can think of is making it pushed by another element.

Comment: Check your memory usage. once the site is downloaded to the browser, the browser does the rest for display.

Comment: It's not my computer lagging.  This video [here](https://youtu.be/kJq8MuUJru4) might get you a better idea of what I'm asking for.  In the video, the orange element the browser isn't moving faster as I wanted.  How would I make that move faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what you want, but I'm not sure. Try giving the orange box a:

```
.center { margin: 0 auto;}
```

That will center it and make it move faster towards the left on resize =)

CodePen here: [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXrbPr)